# How do unsubscribed customers while in a journey works

Tags: marketing-cloud

If a contact has unsubscribed from a list while in a journey will he continue to receive mails as long as he is not exited from journey?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you have set up the Email Activity on your Journey.

When you are configuring a the event, there is a setting [**Delivery Options**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5) on which it's mandatory to specifiy a Publication List.

[image: Delivery]

By default it will be All Subscribers list. Which means if a Contact has unsubscribed from All Subscribers, then upon reaching this Email Activity there will be a check if this Contact is still Subscribed or has it been Unsubscribed.

If Contact is Unsubscribed then this Email Activity will **not** send an Email and Contact will continue forward in the Journey.